# How to handle RTK query errors in getServerSideProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, rtk-query

I passed a slug that was not in database through url and it threw me this error which i don't know how to handle.

[![Error Message thrown by RTK Query]
[image]

Here is my getServerSideProps logic.
[image: getServerSideProps Logic]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It seems like I found a solution but are there any other ways to do this in a performant way as I don't want to keep repeating it for every single request.

Comment: Just a suggestion for the future, that posting images of code is not nearly as valuable as posting the code itself in text format. 
Here are great reasons why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5258419